# Issue with "dynamic" padding in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, pyqt, pyqt4

I've been trying to set a fixed size padding (in  pixels) on my matplotlib figure. I've never been able to find a solution that suits my needs on the internet so I had to make a little workaround for this, which is done with the following code :

```
def resizeEvent(self,e):
    windowWidth=self.geometry().width()
    windowHeight=self.geometry().height()
    #print(windowWidth,windowHeight)
    figure.subplots_adjust(left=100.0/windowWidth,right=1-100.0/windowWidth, top=1-100.0/windowHeight,bottom=100.0/windowHeight)
```

It works fine when manually resizing the window (we have a padding of 100px on every side).

Unfortunatly, when clicking *Maximize*, the padding (in 0 to 1) seems to be **equal to it's previous value**, even if the **print returns the correct window size** (1920px).
A second click to *Restore Down* will then set the padding to the value we should have when we maximized it.

[image: Explanation with a picture :]

I don't really get what's happening here, I must be missing something...
Tell me if you need more information such as more code.

Thank you for your kind help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had similar issues in the past (the figure not resizing at start up) and moved the recalculation of the figure subplots to the `draw` method. Something like this (I use tight_layout but you get the idea):

```
class PlotWidget(FigureCanvas):

    def __init__(self):
        self.__resizing_needed = True

    def draw(self):
        if self.__resizing_needed:
            self.__resizing_needed = False
            try:
                self.figure.tight_layout()
            except ValueError:
                # Set the minimumSize of this widget to prevent this
                print('Plot too small.')

        super(PlotWidget, self).draw()

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        self.__resizing_needed = True
        super(PlotWidget, self).resizeEvent(event)
```

Comment: yeah Indeed redrawing is required in this case. But as I has many figures of my plot the draw() was a bit to slow so I made the application redraw on maximize and restore only :).